# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2+x+1}{x^6+x^4+1} dx$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2+x+1}{x^6+x^4+1} dx $$

Wolfram says $1.80276\ldots $

Calculating this seems complicated to me because the residues are pretty hard to find and I have tried the infinite residue method but it didn't work out.

Comment: Where's this problem coming from? Homework? Also are you interested only in complex analysis methods?

Comment: Worse than homework, this was given on a recent exam :s

Comment: If this is the exact integral I wouldn't waste too much time on it, I daresay it's a garbage integral especially to put into an exam. However are you sure there's no typo? Having a decent denominator would change things easily. IMO this one would fit well into an exam:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2+x+1}{x^6+x^4+x^2+1} dx$$ 
Do you have a picture by any chance with the given integral?

Comment: I agree with you, maybe there was some error and the integral you mentioned was the one, it could be easily factored.

Comment: Here's the first $100$ digits of the integral: 1.802760229617293521730304221202219198579214828616746966058211626033206999972800311238224237440063117. Mathematica cannot find a nice closed form for this integral however (within the time which I set it running on my machine),  so it seems likely this has no nice answer. (Although I could be wrong on this.)

Comment: Sadly I don't have the paper but some colleagues got this on the exam, glad it wasn't me lol.

Comment: Depends how you view it, but your colleagues might be the lucky ones as they might get free full points on the exercise after/ **if** (so someone might need to inform that matter) the professor realises there's something wrong with the integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Without complex analysis.*

From a formal point of view, there is closed form solution.

Let $(a,b,c)$ to be the roots of $y^3+y^2+1=0$; one is real and negative (say $a$) and the other two $(b,c)$ are complex conjugate.
$$\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^6+x^4+1}=\frac{x^2+x+1}{(x^2-a)(x^2-b)(x^2-c)}$$ Now, using partial fraction decomposition, the rhs write
$$-\frac{1}{(a-b) (a-c) (b-c)}\left(\frac{(x+a+1) (c-b)}{x^2-a}+\frac{(b-a) (x+c+1)}{x^2-c}+\frac{(a-c) (x+b+1)}{x^2-b} \right)$$ So, we face three integrands of the form
$$\frac{A+B x}{x^2-d}=\frac{A}{x^2-d}+\frac B 2\frac {2x}{x^2-d }$$
$$\int_0^t \frac{A+B x}{x^2-d}\,dx=-\frac{A}{\sqrt{d}}\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{d}}\right)+\frac B 2 \log \left(1-\frac{t^2}{d}\right)$$ Now, the problem is to make $t\to \infty$ and to simplify.

The real solution is given by
$$a=-\frac{1}{3} \left(1+2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{29}{2}\right)\right)\right)$$ I prefer to avoid typing the explicit solutions of$(b,c)$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$
$\newcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}$

Split the integral $I$ as $I=I_0+I_1$
$$\begin{align}
I_0&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(x^2+1)\d x}{x^6+x^4+1} \\
I_1&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x\,\d x}{x^6+x^4+1}\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Replace $x\leftarrow 1/x$, $\d x \leftarrow -\d x /x^2$.

$$\begin{align}
I_0&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(x^4+x^2)\d x}{x^6+x^2+1} \\
I_1&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^3\,\d x}{x^6+x^2+1}\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Replace $x\leftarrow \sqrt{x}$, $\d x \leftarrow \d x /(2\sqrt{x})$:

$$\begin{align}
I_0&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(x+1)\sqrt{x}\,\d x}{x^3+x+1} \\
I_1&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x\,\d x}{x^3+x+1}\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Let $H$ be the positive-oriented Hankel "keyhole" contour about the negative real axis, *viz.*, the conventional branch cut of $\sqrt{x}$. Then
$$\begin{align}I_0&=\frac{1}{4\i}\oint_H\frac{(x-1)\sqrt{x}\d x}{x^3+x-1}\\
I_1&=\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{x\,\d x}{x^3+x-1}\text{.}
\end{align}$$

---

We make free use of standard notation for [divided differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences#Notation). Let $f$ and $g$ be analytic. Let $a$ be a simple root of $f$, and let $g$ be nonzero near $a$. Then

$$\frac{g(x)f'(a)}{f(x)}=\frac{g(a)}{x-a}+\frac{f'(a)g[x,a]-f[x,a,a]g(a)}{f[x,a]}$$
so that, if $a$ is the (unique, positive) real solution to $x^3+x-1$ guaranteed by the rule of signs,

$$\frac{g(x)(3a^2+1)}{x^3+x-1}=\frac{g(a)}{x-a}+\frac{(3a^2+1)g[x,a]-(x+2a)g(a)}{x^2+ax+a^2+1}$$

$$\begin{split}\frac{(3a^2+1)x}{x^3+x-1}&=\frac{a}{x-a}+\frac{a^2+1-ax}{x^2+ax+a^2+1}\\
&=\frac{a}{x-a}-\frac{a(x+\tfrac{a}{2})}{(x+\tfrac{a}{2})^2+\tfrac{3}{4}a^2+1}+\frac{\tfrac{3}{2}a^2+1}{(x+\tfrac{a}{2})^2+\tfrac{3}{4}a^2+1}
\end{split}$$

whence
$$\begin{split}I_1&=\frac{1}{3a^2+1}\left.\left(\tfrac{a}{2}\ln\frac{(x-a)^2}{x^2+ax+a^2+1}+\frac{\tfrac{3}{2}a^2+1}{\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{4}a^2+1}}\arctan \frac{x+\tfrac{a}{2}}{\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{4}a^2+1 }}\right)\right\rvert_{-\infty}^0 \\
&=\frac{1}{3a^2+1}\left(-\frac{a}{2}\ln\frac{a^2+1}{a^2}+\frac{3a^2+2}{\sqrt{3a^2+4}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan \frac{a}{\sqrt{3a^2+4 }}\right)\right) \end{split}$$

---

By the residue theorem and results above we know that (abbreviate $g(x)=(x-1)\sqrt{x}$)
$$\begin{split}I_0&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{r:r^3+r-1=0}\mathrm{Res}_r\frac{g(x)}{x^3+x-1}\\
&= -\frac{\pi}{2(3a^2+1)}\left(g(a)+\sum_{r:r^2+ar+a^2+1=0}\mathrm{Res}_r\frac{(3a^2+1)g[x,a]-(x+2a)g(a)}{x^2+ax+a^2+1}\right)\text{.}\end{split}$$

But for residues in the quadratic case,
$$(\mathrm{Res}_b+\mathrm{Res}_{b'})\frac{g(x)}{(x-b)(x-b')}=g[b,b']$$

so that if $b$ and $b'$ are the conjugate roots then
$$I_0= -\frac{\pi}{2(3a^2+1)}\left(g(a)+(3a^2+1)g[a,b,b']-g(a)\right)\text{.}$$

But
$$(3a^2+1)g[a,b,b']-g(a)=-g(b)-g(b')+g_a[b,b']$$
where $g_a(x)=(x-a)g(x)$ so

$$\begin{split}I_0&= -\frac{\pi}{2(3a^2+1)}\left(g(a)-g(b)-g(b')+g_a[b,b']\right)\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2(3a^2+1)}\left(g(a)-2\Re g(b)+\frac{\Im b g(b)-a\Im g(b)}{\Im b}\right) \end{split}\text{.}$$

Using the half-angle formula, we can get an unambiguous expression in terms of $a$ and square roots:

$$I_0=-\frac{\pi}{2(3a^2+1)}\left((a-1)\sqrt{a} +\frac{-3a^2+6a+2-2\sqrt{1+a^2}(5a+4)}{3a^2+1}\sqrt{\tfrac{(\sqrt{1+a^2}+a/2)^3}{2}}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

I will type some rows on the given integral. To have full human details it would be too much, the reason being the final result. Most calculations are done using a computer algebra system, here [sage](https://www.sagemath.org), but in a manner that is close to a human.

Let us split the integral in two, compute first:
$$
J 
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2+1}{x^6+x^4+1} \;dx
=\frac 12\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{x^2+1}{x^6+x^4+1} \;dx
\ .
$$
The integral over $\Bbb R$ is written as usual as the limit of an integral over $[-R,R]$, where $R\to \infty$. We take a D-contour (with the | in D on the horizontal axis) and use the Residue Theorem, after showing that the half circle ")" part of the integral has no contribution in the limit. The result is
$$
J =\frac 12\cdot 2\pi i\sum_{a\text{ residue with Im}a >0}
\operatorname{Res}_{z=a}\frac{z^2+1}{z^6+z^4+1}\ .
\tag{$1$}
$$
Let $a_1,a_2,a_3;a_4,a_5,a_6$ be the zeros of the denominator $z^6+z^4+1$, the first three of them being located in the upper half plane. Then the residue in $a_1$ is the value of
$$
\frac{z^2+1}{(z-a_2)(z-a_3)(z-a_4)(z-a_5)(z-a_6)}
$$
computed in $z=a_1$. Similarly we compute the residues in $a_2,a_3$. It is time to let the computer do some work.

```
sage: var('z');
sage: roots = (z^6 + z^4 + 1).roots(ring=QQbar, multiplicities=False)
sage: upper_roots = [ r for r in roots if r.imag() > 0 ]
sage: lower_roots = [ r for r in roots if r.imag() < 0 ]
sage: a1, a2, a3 = upper_roots
sage: a4, a5, a6 = lower_roots
sage: upper_roots
[-0.7276046225775957? + 0.544630949228835?*I,
 1.210607794406086?*I,
 0.7276046225775957? + 0.544630949228835?*I]
sage: lower_roots
[-0.7276046225775957? - 0.544630949228835?*I,
 -1.210607794406086?*I,
 0.7276046225775957? - 0.544630949228835?*I]
sage: def res(a):    return (a^2+1)/prod( [a-r for r in roots if r != a] )                                              
sage: res1 = res(a1)
sage: res2 = res(a2)
sage: res3 = res(a3)
sage: res_sum = res1 + res2 + res3
sage: res_sum
0.?e-17 - 0.4195605201895775?*I
```

Note that sage is performing all above computations exactly, using algebraic numbers, numbers in `QQbar`$=\bar{\Bbb Q}$. We can for instance ask for

```
sage: res1.minpoly()
x^6 + 5/62*x^4 + 87/15376*x^2 + 1/61504

sage: res1
0.1319727669669131? - 0.2371518226609966?*I
sage: res2
0.?e-19 + 0.05474312513241570?*I
sage: res3
-0.1319727669669131? - 0.2371518226609966?*I
```

The values of the residues in $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are  roots of the above polynomial.
It turns out that it is simpler to compute their sum (as an element in $\bar{\Bbb Q}$) if we start with the above polynomial and identify the roots.

```
sage: values = ( x^6 + 5/62*x^4 + 87/15376*x^2 + 1/61504 ).roots(ring=QQbar, multiplicities=False)
sage: values
[-0.1319727669669131? - 0.2371518226609966?*I,
 -0.1319727669669131? + 0.2371518226609966?*I,
 -0.05474312513241570?*I,
 0.05474312513241570?*I,
 0.1319727669669131? - 0.2371518226609966?*I,
 0.1319727669669131? + 0.2371518226609966?*I]
sage: Res1, Res2, Res3 = values[4], values[3], values[0]
sage: Res1 + Res2 + Res3
0.?e-19 - 0.4195605201895775?*I

sage: _.minpoly()                                                                                                       
x^8 + 10/31*x^6 - 6/961*x^4 - 4/961*x^2 + 1/3844
```

So the residues sum in the formula $(1)$ expressing $J$ it the root of the above biquadratic polynomial near $0.4195605201895775\dots\; I$ and i do not want to spend any further words, except for a numerical check:

```
sage: (Res1+Res2+Res3).n() * pi.n() * I
1.31808824796389 + 1.70306079004328e-19*I
sage: numerical_integral( lambda x: (x^2+1)/(x^6+x^4+1), (0, oo) )[0]
1.3180882479638856
```

and the hint that things are complicated:

```
sage: P = ((Res1 + Res2 + Res3)^2).minpoly()
sage: P.galois_group()
Transitive group number 5 of degree 4
sage: _.structure_description()
'S4'
sage: P
x^4 + 10/31*x^3 - 6/961*x^2 - 4/961*x + 1/3844
```

---

It is time to pass to the other integral.
$$
K 
= 
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^6+x^4+1} \;dx
= 
\frac 12\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x^2)^3+(x^2)^2+1} \;d(x^2)
= 
\frac 12\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y^3+y^2+1} \;dy
\ .
$$
Sage delivers an exact value of the above, using expressions involving $\pi$, $\log$, $\arctan$ and the roots of the denominator, which looks like a mess, and it would be an injury to post it here.

(Imagine a partial fraction decomposition of the above fraction over $\bar{\Bbb Q}$, using the roots $r_1,r_2,r_3$ of $y^3+y^2+1$, then integrate the $\log(y-r)$ from $0$ to some $R$, then pass to the limit...)

---

I have to stop here with the fair wish that the examiner would digest his / her own medicine, and post here the true, quick, full points answer.

Answer (score 1):

Calculations are done only using a computer algebra system with Mathematica

MMA code:

```
LaplaceTransform[Integrate[InverseLaplaceTransform[(x^2 + x + 1)/(x^6 + x^4 + a), a, s], {x, 
 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> Re[s] > 0], s, a, Assumptions -> a > 0] /. a -> 1 // Simplify

 (*1/216 (-36 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1, 1}, {2/3, 4/3}, -(4/27)] - (
 1/\[Pi])3 Gamma[2/
 3] (2 Gamma[-(2/3)] Gamma[-(1/3)] Gamma[4/
    3] HypergeometricPFQ[{5/12, 11/12, 7/6}, {2/3, 4/3}, -(4/
     27)] + 3 Gamma[1/3]^2 Gamma[2/
    3] HypergeometricPFQ[{7/12, 5/6, 13/12}, {2/3, 4/3}, -(4/
     27)]) + \[Pi] ((72 (2/(29 + 3 Sqrt[93]))^(1/3))/Sqrt[31] + (
  36 2^(2/3) (29 + 3 Sqrt[93])^(1/3))/Sqrt[31] + (
  432 Gamma[7/
    6] HypergeometricPFQ[{1/12, 7/12, 5/6}, {1/3, 2/3}, -(4/27)])/
  Gamma[1/6] + 
  36 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/4, 1/2, 3/4}, {1/3, 2/3}, -(4/27)] + 
  9/2 HypergeometricPFQ[{3/4, 5/4, 3/2}, {4/3, 5/3}, -(4/27)] + 
  5 HypergeometricPFQ[{11/12, 7/6, 17/12}, {4/3, 5/3}, -(4/27)]))*)

  N[%, 100]
  (*1.802760229617293521730304221202219198579214828616746966058211626033206999972800311238224237440063117 + 0.*10^-100 I *)
```

LaTex code:

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^2+x+1}{x^6+x^4+1} \, dx=\\\frac{1}{216} \left(-36 \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3};-\frac{4}{27}\right)-
   \frac{3 \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \left(2 \Gamma
   \left(-\frac{2}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{4}{3}\right) \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{5}{12},\frac{11}{12},\frac{7}{6};\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3
   };-\frac{4}{27}\right)+3 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{7}{12},\frac{5}{6},\frac{13}{12};\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3
   };-\frac{4}{27}\right)\right)}{\pi }+\pi  \left(\frac{72
   \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{29+3 \sqrt{93}}}}{\sqrt{31}}+\frac{36\ 2^{2/3}
   \sqrt[3]{29+3 \sqrt{93}}}{\sqrt{31}}+\frac{432 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{7}{6}\right) \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{12},\frac{7}{12},\frac{5}{6};\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}
   ;-\frac{4}{27}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}+36 \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4};\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3};-
   \frac{4}{27}\right)+\frac{9}{2} \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2};\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{3};-
   \frac{4}{27}\right)+5 \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{11}{12},\frac{7}{6},\frac{17}{12};\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{
   3};-\frac{4}{27}\right)\right)\right)$$